# Problema al publicar una aplicación ASP.NET en IIS local

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

para comenzar soy bastante nuevo en la programación en ASP.NET MVC, por lo tanto realizo la pregunta correspondiente y en caso de poder realizar criticas constructivas hacia mi metodologia de programacion seran bienvenidas.

El problema: estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.6), a la hora de Debuguear no hay problema alguno, todas las librerias y paginas funcionan correctamente.
Pero a la hora de publicar la aplicación en IIS en mi maquina a modo de testear funcionalidades de la pagina de manera remota (con varias pcs) me encuentro con los siguientes errores.

1- La pagina principal carga de manera correcta, pero luego de loguear deberia redigir hacia otra pagina y es alli en donde me encuentro con el error 404. De manera manual coloque en la URL las credenciales (datos de loguin) que solicita el Action para hacer la redirección, y me dirige de manera correcta hacia el sitio. Añado capturas para saber si me esta faltando alguna configuracion en IIS, o estoy realizando mal la redirección.

[image: La ubicación en donde publico en IIS]

[image: La página inicial en donde solicita el loguin]

[image: El error devuelto tras hacer click en el boton ingresar]

[image: La página a la que debería redireccionar pero ingresando manualmente los parametros]

El código en el controlador MainController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MainLogued(string userInput, string passInput)
    {
        using (GlobConnEntities bd = new GlobConnEntities())
        {
            Usuario user = bd.Usuario.Where(b => b.Usuario1 == userInput && b.Contraseña == passInput).FirstOrDefault();

            if(user == null)
            {
                //string Error = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";

                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                usuarioLogueado = user;

                return View("MainLogued", usuarioLogueado);
            }
        }
    }
```

El código en la pagina desde donde hago el llamado al action:

```
<form action="/Main/MainLogued" method="post">
                <p class="rightSection-menu-item">
                    Iniciar sesión
                </p>
                <input id="userLog" class="rightSection-menu-item" type="text" name="userInput" placeholder="Usuario">
                <input id="passLog" class="rightSection-menu-item" type="password" name="passInput" placeholder="Contraseña">
                <input class="rightSection-menu-item" type="submit" value="Ingresar">
                <a class="rightSection-menu-item" href="https://google.com.ar">
                    ¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?
                </a>
                <a class="rightSection-menu-item" onclick="abrirRegistro()">
                    ¿Aún no te has registrado?
                </a>
            </form>
```

Tengo otro problema pero creo que ya la pregunta se ha vuelto extensa, disculpas por las imagenes y si se hizo muy extenso, quise ser lo mas claro posible y espero puedan ayudarme ya que como he dicho, soy nuevo en MVC y no se que tan buenas sean mis prácticas a la hora del código.

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal cual como lo tienes cuando haces la peticion la url apunta hacia otra ruta que no existe.

Una forma de hacerlo es con `Url.Action`:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("MiAccion", "MiControlador")" method="post">
    <p class="rightSection-menu-item">
        Iniciar sesión
    </p>
    <input id="userLog" class="rightSection-menu-item" type="text" name="userInput" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input id="passLog" class="rightSection-menu-item" type="password" name="passInput" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input class="rightSection-menu-item" type="submit" value="Ingresar">
    <a class="rightSection-menu-item" href="https://google.com.ar">
        ¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?
    </a>
    <a class="rightSection-menu-item" onclick="abrirRegistro()">
        ¿Aún no te has registrado?
    </a>
</form>
```

Otra forma es utilizar `BeginForm`:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MiAccion", "MiControlador", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p class="rightSection-menu-item">
        Iniciar sesión
    </p>
    <input id="userLog" class="rightSection-menu-item" type="text" name="userInput" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input id="passLog" class="rightSection-menu-item" type="password" name="passInput" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input class="rightSection-menu-item" type="submit" value="Ingresar">
    <a class="rightSection-menu-item" href="https://google.com.ar">
        ¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?
    </a>
    <a class="rightSection-menu-item" onclick="abrirRegistro()">
        ¿Aún no te has registrado?
    </a>
}
```

Solo reemplaza `MiAccion` y `MiControlador` con los nombre que tienes en tu proyecto.

*Nota: los ejemplos que te coloco no han sido probados, solo es una forma de como deberias hacerlo y lo tomes como guia*.

> [Url.Action](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2): Genera una URL completa para un método de acción
>   utilizando el nombre de acción y el nombre del controlador
>   especificados.
>
> [Html.BeginForm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2): Es el método de extensión del ayudante HTML que
>   se utiliza para crear y representar el formulario en HTML.

Comment: En efecto tu respuesta solucionó mi inconveniente!
Utilicé el primer método y corre perfecto, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema en realidad lo tienes en el Controlador que hace el inicio de sesión y que luego redirige a MainLoged, ya que al iniciar sesión redirige a

192.168.1.108/Main/MainLoged

Cuando debería redirigir a

192.168.1.108/ClobConn/Main/MainLoged

En el ambiente de pruebas no tienes problemas pues no existe la carpeta ClobConn/ y en lugar de eso el servidor de pruebas de Visual Studio utiliza la ruta directa locahost/:puerto/Main/MainLoged.

Lo mas probable que es al momento de redirigir a Main/MainLoged estás utilizando una ruta absoluta en lugar de una ruta relativa. Si pones el código de tu controlador y tu vista podría darte mas información al respecto.